# Git track files on existing project (and without clone first)

Tags: git, github

All my projects on my local machine are stored without the '.git' directory, since I don't want to store it (it's too large). Each time I need to work on some project, and update later on GitHub, I just open a new directory, clone the repo from GitHub, and replace all the files there with the updated files, and then just

```
git add . 
git commit -m 'my commit'
git push
```

I was wondering if there is a shorter way to do it, without keeping the '.git' directory for each project. For example, I opened the project and did:

```
git init
git remote add origin https://github.com/username/my-project.git
```

But in the VSCode I see that all the files are marked as "created" (green).

What I want is to work on my project without having cloned it before. Just do `git init`, and another command to download the updated '.git' directory, that will track my files from that moment.

Thanks.

Comment: You seem to be trying to use git without actually using git.  It might be easier to describe your end-goal.  What's wrong with having the .git directory?  Because the objects from the upstream are too large?

Comment: Yup. The '.git' directory is very big and I don't want to keep it. I just want to open a project, and track the project's files without cloning the project first.

Comment: but the .git directory essentially IS git. You can't do anything without it

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. Your .git directory shouldn't be large. A common problem that causes this is people checking in binary files, don't do that

Comment: You should state clearly in the question that your problem is that the upstream .git directory is very large because **they** checked in large files -- it wasn't your fault.

Comment: I don't understand how "the repo is big" and "I clone the complete repo when I want to push" live together. Can you give more details about that ? (the size you see on disk, the time it takes to clone, what you gain by deleting the repo afterwards)

Comment: also : search SO for `git clone --depth 1` and shallow clones

Answer (score 0):

In the good old days of early remote source tracking (cvs/svn/etc), we did it this way:

Create our repository:

```
git init
```

Then extract their code into it:

```
rsync -avh ../their_source/ ./
```

Then add all the files:

```
git add .
git commit -m "their version 1.0"
```

Then we make **our changes in a branch**

```
git checkout -b our_changes
# modify something
git add modified_file
git commit -m "modified a file"
...
```

When we get a new copy of their code:

```
git checkout main
rsync -avh ../their_new_source/ ./
git add .
git commit -m "imported version 1.1"
```

Then go back to our code and move the changes we've made on top of theirs:

```
git checkout our_changes
git rebase main
```

This will do what you want: track releases of their code without **all** of their changes.